# MongoDB crashes after connecting initially and then trying to import Models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm deploying my app to Heroku, and Im getting this crash report

[image: img]

It starts in `uploads.js` where I import the Models,

```
// models
const { User, Post, Error } = require("../../constants/models");
```

Here is `models.js`,

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    User: require("../models/User"),
    Post: require("../models/Post"),
    Error: require("../models/Error")
})
```

Here is `User`,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

console.log("\n\n\nentering user");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
. . . .
```

Here is `Post`,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

console.log("\n\n\nentering post");

const postSchema = new Schema({
. . . .
```

And `Error` and `Notification` are the same.

What could be going on? If I comment out `const { User, Post, Error } = require("../../constants/models");`, then everything is ok.. (ignore the 'should not be printed yet' comment)

[image: img2]

Is it perhaps because I cant require the same models more than once? But then how would other modules access mongoose models if I dont `require` them at the top?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't need details of your current project, nor partial code listings from. Just supply the **minimal** amount of code in order to reproduce the problem. Then there is a basis to diagnose what is exactly wrong. Please also **no screenshots**. Your console screens are made up of "text", just like the code you are going to write to show the **minimal** case to replicate what you see here. That's all that's needed.

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce it.. When I'm on my personal hotspot, it works. When I deploy to Heroku, it shows me that.

Comment: Write some code along the lines of what you "think" might be causing the problem. Start small, and keep adding things until it breaks. if you don't understand why it breaks at that point, then post a question here. I believe that is basically what the link you were asked to read actually says ( in the 200 chars of less version that is ). Perhaps actually read it and follow the instruction. That is what is expected of posts of this nature. We are not sitting at your desk and cannot debug your entire code base.